# Which is a better database design and why?

Tags: database-design

If you have two tables "Checklist" and "ChecklistItems" where every checklistItem will belong to exactly 1 checklist.

Would you prefer having a foreign key referring the "Checklist" in the "ChecklistItems" table, or would you create a separate table defining the connection between the checklist and items?

Example:

```
class Checklist {
  public int ID; // Primary Key
  public String Description;
}

class ChecklistItem {
  public int ID; // Primary Key
  public String Description;
  public int ChecklistID; // Foreign key
}
```

OR:

```
class Checklist {
  public int ID; // Primary Key
  public String Description;
}

class ChecklistItem {
  public int ID; // Primary Key
  public String Description;
}

class ChecklistAndChecklistItem {
  public int ChecklistID; //  primary key 1 AND foreign Key constraint
  public String ChecklistItemID //  primary key 2 AND Foreign Key constraint;
```

}

Why would you do it the way you would?

Comment: Time to read a book on information modeling, the relational model & database design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first. It's a standard one-to-many relation, so it should be modeled as such.

The second approach, using the association table, is inferior for a number of reasons:

- The extra table just eats up extra disk/memory space.
- Your join queries become slower because you have to join 3 tables instead of 2.
- You'd have to specify additional constraints on the association table to express the one-to-many nature of the relationship.